# Timeout for launching a bash command in perl

Tags: perl

I have a usecase where I have to fire a bash command from perl and need that command to exit within a specified timeout
Currently I am using this moudle

```
use System::Timeout qw(timeout);
timeout(10, "my bash script")
```

(As timeout is necessary I am not using system() to make the call)

This function returns 1 if shell script exitted with non-zero exit code or the command timed out.

**Issues**

1. This function returns just 1 / 0 based on the command passed or failed(I need the exact exit code of the bash script)
2. If it is 1, I do not get to know if script exitted with a non-zero exit code OR there was a timeout(Distinguish between a timeout and shell script failure)
3. pid of called process is unknown (so that if the scipt fails due to timeout, I need to kill it)

It is important for me to satisfy both of the above criteria(I know very well how to do this in python, but could not get a solution for perl)

I do not know if forking a current process in perl and then monitoring it with SIGALRM will help
(Forking will give me pid of the forked process and NOT the bash script which I have launched from that fork. Will killing the fork, also kill the bash process it launched?)

Thanks for the help

Comment: For the exitcode, here is quick fix: You can try write it to a file `timeout(6, 'myscript.sh; echo $? > exitcode.txt');` If the file does not exist after the `timeout` you can be sure it timed out.

Comment: *"if the script fails due to timeout, I need to kill it"* : I think if the script fails due to timeout, the `timeout()` will kill it. So then you would not need to obtain the PID?

Answer (score 2):

For advanced tasks when running external commands, [`IPC::Run`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) is a fairly good choice. The following should cover all the cases you mentioned. (I admit that using a regex on the error message is not the most elegant solution, but the point here was to demo the possibilities with this module.)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use IPC::Run qw/ start timeout /;
use Try::Tiny;

my @commands = (
        ['perl','-e','sleep 1'], # success
        ['perl','-e','sleep 10'], # failure due to timeout
        ['perl','-e','exit 123'], # failure due to nonzero exit code
        ['perl','-e','kill "INT", $$'], # process exits due to signal
        ['this_command_doesnt_exist'], # other failure
    );

for my $cmd (@commands) {
    my $h;
    try {
        print "\nRunning ",join(' ',@$cmd),"\n";
        $h = start $cmd, timeout(2);
        $h->finish or die "finish with \$?=$?";
        print "Success\n";
    }
    catch {
        if (/timeout/i) {
            warn "Timeout Error: $_";
            warn "killing child process\n";
            defined $h && $h->kill_kill;
        }
        elsif (/\$\?/) {
            warn "Exit Code Error: $_";
            # from http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html
            if ($? == -1) { print "failed to execute: $!\n" }
            elsif ($? & 127)
                { printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
                    ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without' }
            else { printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8 }
        }
        else { warn "Other Error: $_" }
    };
}
```

Output (slightly redacted):

```
Running perl -e sleep 1
Success

Running perl -e sleep 10
Timeout Error: IPC::Run: timeout on timer #2 at ...
killing child process

Running perl -e exit 123
Exit Code Error: finish with $?=31488 at ...
child exited with value 123

Running perl -e kill "INT", $$
Exit Code Error: finish with $?=2 at ...
child died with signal 2, without coredump

Running this_command_doesnt_exist
Other Error: Command 'this_command_doesnt_exist' not found in ... at ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your system might have the gnu `timeout` command which sets an exit code of 124 if it kills the child process with timeout and returns the command exit code otherwise.  If you don't have gnu `timeout`, you did mention you have bash which means you could use my bash emulator for gnu `timeout`, https://github.com/ronaldxs/bash-timeout, and I would happily look forward to any feedback.  Looking at the source code for `System::Timeout`, it is based on CPAN module `IPC::Cmd` which suggests the following as another starting point:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dump;

use IPC::Cmd 'run_forked';

my $rc = run_forked('sleep 5; exit 3', { timeout => 2 });

dd $rc;
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
  child_pgid       => 69066,
  err_msg          => "ran more than [2] seconds\n",
  exit_code        => 0,
  ...
  timeout          => 2,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the approaches by @mr_ron and @haukex in the other answers. Using a well tested module like `IPC::Run` or `IPC::Cmd` is the safe approach. Anyway, I have experimented a little bit with a more low level approach here:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Select;
use IPC::Open3;
use Symbol 'gensym';

# specify a command and a timeout
my $cmd = 'echo Hello; sleep 5; echo Bye; exit 2';
my $timeout = 3;

# Run the command with the given timeout:
local $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE'; # Automatically reap dead children
my $cmd_err = gensym;
my $cmd_pid = open3( my $cmd_in, my $cmd_out, $cmd_err, $cmd );
say "Command PID: ", $cmd_pid;
my $timer_err = gensym;
my $timer_pid = open3( my $timer_in, my $timer_out, $timer_err, "sleep $timeout" );

my $timed_out = 0;
# We only use STDOUT here for simplicity, if needed you can also add
#  the STDERR handle of the command to the select loop..
my $select = IO::Select->new($cmd_out, $timer_out);
OUTER: while (1) {
    my @ready = $select->can_read;
    for my $fh (@ready) {
        my $fd   = $fh->fileno();
        if ( $fd == $timer_out->fileno() ) {
            say "Timed out";
            $timed_out = 1;
            last OUTER;
        }
        else { # The command handle is ready for reading..
            my $line = <$fh>;
            # An undefined value for $line, signals that the command processes
            #  has finished..
            last OUTER if !defined $line;
            print $line; # echo the line from the command to our STDOUT
        }
    }
}
if ( $timed_out ) {
    kill 'KILL', $cmd_pid;
}
else { # The command finished first, the timer may still be running..
    kill 'KILL', $timer_pid;
    waitpid( $cmd_pid, 0 );  # Reap the child, and get exit code
    my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;
    say "Exit code: ", $child_exit_status;
}
```